# Comparing lat/long values in Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, if-statement, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with a number of markers on it. Because of the way it is set up, one marker will always coincide with the centre of the map. I want to show a different icon on that marker to all the others.

The markers and their corresponding info box are defined with this function:

```
function createMarker(latlng, html, summary, photo1, photo2, thisLatlng) {
    var contentString = "<div style='min-height:150px'>" + photo1 + "<img src='/images/" + photo2 + "' width='225' height='150' align='left' style='margin-right:8px;border:none'></a><span class='title'>" + html +"</span><br>" + summary + "</div>";

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: thisicon,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        ib.close(map, marker);
        boxText.innerHTML = contentString;
        ib.open(map, marker);
        });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        ib.close(map, marker);
        });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```

"latlng" is the a lat/long that is different for each marker. "thisLatlng" is the centre of the map and the lat/long of one specific marker.

My intention was to use something like this to determine the correct icon to use:

```
if(latlng===thisLatlng){
    var thisicon = icon1;
}else{
    var thisicon = icon2;
}
```

However it's not working as the "if" always returns false. I've tried

```
if(latlng===thisLatlng){
```

and

```
if(latlng==thisLatlng){
```

and I've also tried turning it the other way around with != and !== but they always return false.
I've checked that the two values are equal by printing them one above the other and they look exactly the same (as they should be).

I must be doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`LatLng` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLng) has an equals method.

> **equals**
>   equals(other)
>
> ---
>
> **Parameters:**
>   other:  LatLng
>   Return Value:  boolean
>   Comparison function.

The other option is to compute the difference between the two points and set a threshold (say 1 meter) for "equals"

That said, your existing code (with `===` works for me): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cse394nx/) as does `.equals` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cse394nx/1/))

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var gmarkers = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 19.12170,
      lng: 72.85083
    },
    zoom: 13.5,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  createMarker(map.getCenter(), "center", "summary", "", "", map.getCenter());
  var otherPt = new google.maps.LatLng(19.12, 72.851);
  createMarker(otherPt, "not center", "summary2", "", "", map.getCenter());
}

function createMarker(latlng, html, summary, photo1, photo2, thisLatlng) {
  var contentString = "<div style='min-height:150px'>" + photo1 + "<img src='/images/" + photo2 + "' width='225' height='150' align='left' style='margin-right:8px;border:none'></a><span class='title'>" + html + "</span><br>" + summary + "</div>";

  if (latlng.equals(thisLatlng)) {
    var thisicon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png";
  } else {
    var thisicon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png";
  }
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: thisicon,
  });

}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```